# How to combine dataframes in specific situations?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes as below.

[image]

I want to combine these two dataframes in the following rule.
First, I want to focus on column A,B,C,and D.
If those values are all same among two dataframes, I want to calculate the sum of the value. Also, for column E, I want to leave the df1 value.
The expected outcome is below figure.

[image]

If you could help, I would appreciate it very much.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please post your dataframes and desired output as text, not as images.

Comment: Please post pictures if you want to make it hard for people to answer your questions.

Comment: Absolutely. Next time I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### concat + groupby + sort_values

One way is to concatenate your dataframes, perform a `groupby` operation, then sort values:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[100, 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 1],
                    [50, 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh', 2],
                    [10, 'iii', 'jjj', 'kkk', 'lll', 3]],
                   columns=['Value', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[80, 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 4],
                    [60, 'ej', 'feuajo', 'eiwo', 'fuasdhf', 5],
                    [1, 'gheuha', 'daj;f', 'dfua', 'hfdusu', 6]],
                   columns=['Value', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

res = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)\
        .groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])\
        .agg({'Value': 'sum', 'E': 'first'})\
        .reset_index()\
        .sort_values('Value', ascending=False)

print(res)

        A       B     C        D  Value  E
0     aaa     bbb   ccc      ddd    180  1
2      ej  feuajo  eiwo  fuasdhf     60  5
1     eee     fff   ggg      hhh     50  2
4     iii     jjj   kkk      lll     10  3
3  gheuha   daj;f  dfua   hfdusu      1  6
```

Comment: You must be genius. Thank you very much. Do you happen to know how to erase left column (0,2,1,4,3)?

Comment: @Tom_Hanks, That's called an index, not a column. You can't erase an index, every dataframe must have one. If you write to a file specify `index=False`, e.g. `df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)`.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much, jpp!